# Disable jquery mobile back button conditionally

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing a PhoneGap apps and have the following page flow.

registrationPage > areaSelectionPage > orderDetailPage > areaSelectionPage

I would like the back button only appear on the last areaSelectionPage. If areaSelectionPage is coming from registrationPage, the back button should not appear. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested the code, but you can take the following approach.

`pagebeforeshow` receives two arguments, `event` and `ui`. To get the previous page use, `ui.prevPage` and then apply the check.

```
$("#areaSelectionPage").on('pagebeforeshow', function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.prevPage.attr('id') === 'registrationPage') {
           //hide back button here 
           $('a[data-rel="back"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code is almost perfect. I just need to add the else condition to show the back button again.